# How to Select 3 Unique Items From A Dynamic Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Dynamic array which a sample of that looks like

```
var nums=[25,12,23,47,55,116,17,80,92,150,191,142,13,124,15,176,187,18,19,20,21,30,31];
```

Can you please let me know how I can select 3 unique items from the `nums` and load them to a new array using jQuery of pure JS?

I tried this already

```
 var arr = []
 while(arr.length < 3){
   var randomnumber=Math.ceil(Math.random()*nums.length)
   var found=false;
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i]==randomnumber){found=true;break}
  }
   if(!found)arr[arr.length]=randomnumber;
 }
```

but I am not getting what I want

Comment: You write `3 unique items` in your question, but your comments say you want 3 random, unique items. Which is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (arr.length < 3) {
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*nums.length);
  if (arr.indexOf(nums[randomIndex]) === -1) {
    arr.push(nums[randomIndex])
  }
}
```

Here I create a new random index each time we go through the loop, and then check if that number is already in our result array. If it is not, we push it in, otherwise we just start over.

Comment: What if `nums` has less than three elements or if it doesn't have more than three unique elements?

Answer (score 0):

use `.forEach` on `nums` and push the element if it is unique to the array.

```js
var nums=[25,12,23,47,55,116,17,80,92,150,191,142,13,124,15,176,187,18,19,20,21,30,31];
var arr = [];
nums.forEach(function(v){
   if(arr.length==3) return;
   if(arr.indexOf(v)==-1) arr.push(v);
});
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks Void but this always retuen `[25, 12, 23]`

Answer (score 0):

There is one easy way. First select a random number from the array then splice it out of the array. Then select again. This method guarantees that it will only go through 3 times, unlike selecting a number then testing, which can lead to much longer run times when the number selected approaches the number to select from.

```
var tempArray = original
var arr = []
for(i=0; i<3; i++){
    var n = Math.floor(Math.random()*tempArray.length); //ceil is dangerous, subtract 1 or use floor
    arr[i] = tempArray[n];
    tempArray.splice(n,1);
}
```